# Nexus 5 4G issues

Tags: 4g

I have got a nexus 5 device on O2 network which supposedly has 4G. When I am out and about and not connected to WiFi I use my data. I can have all 4 bars and Hrsp+ yet when I load up play store or Google chrome it can take minutes to load a single webpage
 Why is this, it can be really annoying when I'm out and want to quickly search something and it take 5 minutes to load. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The "bars" actually just state the signal strength – so basically you could have all 5 or whatever bars, but no data at all. Data speed depends on multiple other factors not all fully known to me; one example is "available bandwidth" divided by "connected devices using it".

So if the capacity of the cell tower has been "reached", even with full bars and SuperDuperWhatsnot+++ data connection: highway full means stop-and-go.

Not sure if that's the case with your issue (to find out, you'd need to contact your provider/carrier) – but at least it's one possible explanation. I'd expect the device to switch to another "band" in such a case, though; but it could be there's simply no other one available, or configuration keeps it from doing so.